# Debug Error Occurred in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to debug an open source package, called libprotoident in Eclipse, Kepler version, within Debian. As it has the Makefile, I choose to make an empty Makefile project, and then add all the sources into the workspace. So after that the source compiled and run successfully as in the command line using the Makefile.
As it has 4 apps you can use, I choose to run lpi_protoident package in the run configuration window, as the following image shown.

[image: Run Configuration]

So the Program ran successfully. Now I'm trying to debug it but it generates the following error.

[image: Debug Error Occurred]

How can I solve this error and debug the Project?

Comment: The pictures help identify the context of your error. But the error itself really needs to be in the question otherwise it is not searchable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file you are trying to debug is most likely a shell script created by automake that acts as a wrapper around the real executable, which has been built in a hidden directory.

Instead of telling Eclipse that `tools/protoident/lpi_protoident` is your application, try using `tools/protoident/.libs/lpi_protoident` instead.

Answer (score 0):

### General Answer about the error you are getting

What `not in executable format: File format not reconized` error means is that `lpi_protoident` is not an executable on the platform you are working on.

Are you sure that is an executable you can run (E.g. from the command line)?

There is also the small chance that the GDB you are using is somehow incompatible with the executable, but that is less likely.

### Building libprotoident from source

(Assuming you are trying to build https://github.com/wanduow/libprotoident)

You are trying to build an automake project. The normal way to do that is by configuring to create `Makefile`, you shouldn't be making your own makefile. Please refer to the [README](https://github.com/wanduow/libprotoident/blob/master/README) in the project, but the key parts you need to do are:

> ## Installation
>
> After having installed the required libraries, running the following series of commands should install libprotoident
>
> ```
>     ./bootstrap.sh (only if you've cloned the source from GitHub)
>     ./configure
>     make
>     make install
> ```
>
> By default, libprotoident installs to /usr/local - this can be changed
>   by appending the --prefix= option to ./configure.
>
> The libprotoident tools are built by default - this can be changed by
>   using the
>   --with-tools=no option with ./configure.

Comment: Yes I do. the code works the same within the command line and run mode in the Eclipse. results are all good and acceptable. Is it wrong with my Project creation?! I did this way for another open source project, didn't make it through the Makefile Project. I didn't use the Makefile and it was all good. since I just wnat the lpi_protoident tool to be compiled, I decided to use the Makefile within the project. So do you suggest any better way to import the libprotoident in Eclipse??
And yes, I'm using the open source package you linked.

Comment: Create the project as a makefile project with existing sources

Comment: It didn't solve the problem. it stills generating error in debugging mode.

Comment: Does the program run from the command line? i.e. is this a gdb problem or a program problem? if a gdb problem can you please add to your question details about GDB version and perhaps output of `gdb <name of program>` and then once GDB states do `run`

Comment: yes it runs and everything is fine! Emm.. As I run another program in another project in the same machine in the eclipse, I think the gdb is working well. I'm surprised that it runs normally, it generates results, prints the results as well, and when I try to debug the code it generates error.